# css - separator only on text link not image

Tags: css

Right there are text links and image links.  Each link has a separator.  I would like only the text link to show a separator not the images links.

currently:
Text > image > image > image >

desired:
Text > image image image

thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
#footer
{
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    border:solid 1px #E5E5E5;
}

#footer li 
{
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    padding-left:10px;
}

#footer a
{
    height:30px;
    display:block;
    background-image:url('http://s7.postimg.org/w0nt224pj/bc_separator.png'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-position:right;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#0088CC;
}

ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

    </style>
    <script></script>
</head>
<body background-color: #000000;>




<!-- Footer -->
<div style="width=980px;">
    <ul id="footer">
        <li id="text_separator"><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org/about"><img src="1.png" width="35" height="30" border=1></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org/about"><img src="1.png" width="35" height="30" border=1></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org/about"><img src="1.png" width="35" height="30" border=1></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org/about"><img src="1.png" width="35" height="30" border=1></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you to modify

`#footer a` into `#footer li:nth-child(1)`

here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UGmA2/4/)

update:
maintaining the `#footer a` and add `#footer li:nth-child(1)`

```
#footer a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#0088CC;
}
#footer li:nth-child(1)
{
  height:30px;
  display:block;
  background-image:url('http://s7.postimg.org/w0nt224pj/bc_separator.png'); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  background-position:right;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGmA2/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Give the item you want a class:

```
<li id="text_separator"><a class="separator" href="http://www.stackoverflow.org">Text</a></li>
```

and assign its CSS as such:

```
#footer .separator {
    background-image:url('http://s7.postimg.org/w0nt224pj/bc_separator.png'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-position:right;
}
```

Removing that same assignment from the normal `#footer a` CSS.

[Here is a jsFiddle of it looking as you wish.](http://jsfiddle.net/Kg9GT/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you seperate your css like this :

```
#footer a
{
    height:30px;
    display:block;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#0088CC;
}

#footer li.text_separator a {
    background-image:url('http://s7.postimg.org/w0nt224pj/bc_separator.png'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-position:right;
}
```

And also change the id "text_separator" by a class :

```
<li class="text_separator"><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org">Text</a></li>
```

That way you will be able to apply this css class on others list elements. Id is for unique elements.